# solve the memory error when reading the line number of files in python?

Tags: function, python-2.7, readline

I am trying to read some text files in python, count their line number and finally sum these counting. when the code runs for each file it works until it reaches to a file which has bigger size and I receive this error ' Memory error' . please help me how can I solve it and proceed.

this is my code:

```
def Count_Lines():    
  infile = open(File_Name,'r').read()
  nLine = infile.count('\n')
  print nLine
```

Comment: Read the file one line at a time, increment the counter for each line. (as the highest voted answer to your other question already suggested)

Comment: wld u plz explain it more,if u donot mind

Answer (score 0):

Calling `read()` will read the entire file's content, which might be too big to fit in memory.

This reads the file line by line, avoiding storing the entire content in memory (unless the entire content is one huge line...)

```
count = 0
for file in files:
  with open(file) as F:
    file_count = sum( 1 for line in F )
  count += file_count
```